# Datatable body become blank after sorting or serching problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

After building table body using `.html()` function by jQuery ajax call, sorting searching and export not working, make table blank.

```
var id = $("#userid").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "services/service.php",
    data: {
        cmd: 'get_users',
        id: id
    },
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (res) {
        var html = "";
        l = res.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            html += "<tr><td>" + res[i].id + "</td><td>" + res[i].username + "</td><td>" + res[i].name + "</td><td>" + res[i].role + "</td><td>" + res[i].parent + "</td><td>" + res[i].address + "</td><td>" + res[i].email + "</td><td>" + res[i].mobile_no + "</td><td><button class='uedit'>Edit</button></td><td><button>Delete</button></td></tr>";
        }
        $('#example tbody').html(html);
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you call your sort feature after `$('#example tbody').html(html)`

Answer (score 0):

From this code it seems that table will build properly with user's data when you call this ajax. But what you do while sorting, searching and export, it is important. Check the response of ajax for sorting, searching and export. May be response is empty so empty response makes `response.length = 0` and html will be empty and it is overwrite to `$('#example tbody')` with empty html. html() replaces old elements with new elements.

All this is based on assumption that you get data from server on every sorting, searching and export request. If it is not then show me the code of sorting, searching and export.